# DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ Integration

Tags: integration, administration, docusign

I'm trying to integrate DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ. I've already installed required packages:

- DocuSign for Salesforce
- Salesforce CPQ
- DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ

And configured them.

I wanted now to store in Salesforce the status of the Document Signature in Quote Document Object, but when configuring I could not find the fields and Custom Settings (DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ Settings) that was suposed to be installed with DocuSign for Salesforce and DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ.

Here is the guidelines that I'm following to integrate with:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_docusign_field_link_concept.htm&type=5

The following screenshots show some settings that we've set.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing you set a wrong signature plugin - "**dfscp.Plugin**" instead of "**SBQQDS.DocusignPlugin**". Please check this article about how to do the initial setup of the plugin: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_prepare_for_docusign.htm&type=5

Also, you can check this video for more settings during the setup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxyGwD02UYA